# Fill html table with a database result

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have to build html table that will look like this:
[image]

But the fields and head names I get from database. First query - returns fields description, second query reurns fields values.
I spent a lot hours trying to reach this. So what I do:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($comments as $comment) {   // $comments is array of strings                      
?>
     <td><b><?= $comment ?></b></td>
<?php}?>
</tbody>  
<?php
   foreach ($field_names as $fn) { // $field_names is array_keys($result)
   ?><tr><?php
     foreach ($result as $r) {  // $result - values of fields                          
     ?>
     <td><?= $r[$fn] ?></td>
     <?php
     }?>
</tr>
<?php
}
?></table>
```

But in this way I'm getting my content transposed. Any help, thanks.

Comment: please provide an example of how your array looks like; meaning the content of `$comments` ,  `$fieldnames`. and `$result`

Comment: I showed it at image in my question

Comment: how does your variable `$result` look like? is it just an array of strings?

Comment: oh sorry, I'll update question

Answer (score 0):

ok, since you didnt provide the variable information, i will assume the following, and if so, this code should work for you:

```
<?php
    $comments = ["comm1", "comm2", "comm3"]; // $comments is array of strings

    $field_names = array(
        0 => "fv1",
        1 => "fv2",
        2 => "fv3"
    ); // $field_names is array_keys($result)

    $result = ["value1", "val2", "val3"]// $result - values of fields
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
                    <th><b><?= $comment ?></b></th>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ($field_names as $k => $v) { ?>
                    <td><?= $result[$k] ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

UPDATE:

```
<style>
    .tbl_hdr{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<?php
$comments = ["comm1", "comm2", "comm3"]; // $comments is array of strings
$field_names = array(
   0 => "fv1",
   1 => "fv2",
   2 => "fv3"
); // $field_names is array_keys($result)

$result = ["value1", "val2", "val3"]// $result - values of fields
?>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($field_names as $k => $v) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="tbl_hdr"><?= $comments[$k] ?></td>
            <td><?= $result[$k] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should place `head` fields as a `column` not as a `row`

Comment: ohh i see.. I will make some changes on it soon.